# Conditional calculation based on data in other columns in R

Tags: r

Newbie: I have a data table with 3 columns of categorical values, and I would like to add a fourth column with values calculated by row based on the values of the first 3 columns. So far I have:

```
tC <- textConnection("Visit1    Visit2  Visit3
yes no  no
yes no  yes
yes yes yes")
data1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, tC)
close.connection(tC)
rm(tC)
data1["pattern"] <- NA
```

Next I would like to fill in column 4 such that if the values of visit1, visit2 and visit3 are for example, "yes", "no" and "no", NA would be replaced by "1" in the pattern column for that row. In other languages this would be a FOR loop with some IF statements. I have looked at the apply family, but still not quite sure about best approach and syntax for this in R. Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: What are the other conditions you want? Or is it just the number of "yes" per row?

Comment: Whats the desired output look like for this example?

Comment: It would be nice to get some information or confirmation if we provided answers.

Comment: My post was not very clear. There are 6 possible combinations of "yes" and "no" replies for each row (yes yes yes, yes yes no, yes no no, etc). I would like to create an additional column that would just have values from 1-6 in each row, depending on which combination of yes and no is present in that row.

Comment: There are actually 8 possible combinations, unless your data doesn't allow for all combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are using @SimonO101's expanded sample data, I would suggest `expand.grid` and `factor`.

First, create all the combinations that we are going to have of "yes" and "no" for three columns.

```
facLevs <- expand.grid(c("yes", "no"), c("yes", "no"), c("yes", "no"))
facLevs
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1  yes  yes  yes
# 2   no  yes  yes
# 3  yes   no  yes
# 4   no   no  yes
# 5  yes  yes   no
# 6   no  yes   no
# 7  yes   no   no
# 8   no   no   no
```

Now, we will factor the combinations of the columns. We can use `do.call(paste, ...)` to do this more easily than `apply(mydf, ...)`. We will convert that to `as.numeric` to get the numeric group.

```
mydf$pattern <- as.numeric(factor(do.call(paste, mydf[1:3]), 
                                  do.call(paste, facLevs)))
mydf
#   Visit1 Visit2 Visit3 pattern
# 1    yes     no     no       7
# 2    yes     no    yes       3
# 3    yes    yes    yes       1
# 4     no    yes     no       6
# 5    yes     no    yes       3
```

As you can see, `pattern = 7` corresponds to the values we would find on the seventh row of the `facLevs` `data.frame` that we created.

---

For convenience, here is `mydf`:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Visit1 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes"), 
                       Visit2 = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"), 
                       Visit3 = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")), 
                  .Names = c("Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: +1 and I will remind you that you can always remove your upvote since I edited my answer! This seems more sensible :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to go about this, but we can find the unique rows and then find for each row in the data.frame which of the unique rows it matches. This number is therefore the pattern ID. We have to collapse rows into single string elements though, otherwise R vectorisation gets in the way of what we want. The example below uses the slightly expanded example data:

```
#  Visit1 Visit2 Visit3
#1    yes     no     no
#2    yes     no    yes
#3    yes    yes    yes
#4     no    yes     no
#5    yes     no    yes

#  Get unique combinations
pats <- unique( data1 )

#  Colapse each row to a single string element
pats <- apply( pats , 1 , paste , collapse = " " )

#do the same to your data and compare with the patterns
data1$pattern <- apply( data1 , 1 , function(x) match( paste( x , collapse = " " ) , pats ) )
#  Visit1 Visit2 Visit3 pattern
#1    yes     no     no       1
#2    yes     no    yes       2
#3    yes    yes    yes       3
#4     no    yes     no       4
#5    yes     no    yes       2
```

Comment: Just summing won't work because I have to be able to distinguish between "yes no no" (one pattern) and "no no yes" (another pattern) which both have the same number of yes entries.

Comment: @marcel hold on. Updating. You should have better explained this in the OP.

Comment: @SimonO101, maybe [I shouldn't have been so fast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18704448/1270695) to give you my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

**Answer with for cycle:**

```
updateRow <- function(rIndex, data1) { 
  if ((data1[rIndex, 1] == "yes") && 
      (data1[rIndex, 2] == "no") && 
      (data1[rIndex, 3] == "no")) { 
        data1[rIndex, 4] <- 1
  }   
}

for (i in c(1:3)) updateRow(i, data1); # dim(data1)[2]-1 the column number if you need to change it.
```

You can just change the if as you want. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: This looks like it should work (thanks!). However, the code does not change the contents of column 4:
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE));
tC <- textConnection("Visit1 Visit2 Visit3
yes no no
yes no yes
yes yes yes");
data1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, tC);
close.connection(tC);
rm(tC);
data1["pattern"] <- NA;


updateRow <- function(rIndex) { 
  if ((data1[rIndex, 1] == "yes") && 
      (data1[rIndex, 2] == "no") && 
      (data1[rIndex, 3] == "no")) { 
        data1[rIndex, 4] <- 1
  }   
}

for (i in c(1:NROW(data1))) updateRow(i);

Comment: I updated the code. You have to write the other ifs although.